# Recursive partitioning according to a criterion in R

Tags: r, tree, partitioning, hierarchical-data

I have a dataframe resulting from a grouping:

```
df = structure(
  list(latitude = c(23.13658528, 23.49099973,
    23.49138397, 23.49053121, 23.45386579, 23.44084801,
    23.4463272, 23.78719913, 23.4552457, 23.43415363,
    23.45229713, 23.44412288, 23.439268),
  longitude = c(-11.64711391, -11.67840419, -11.68223218,
    -11.68325966, -11.94486056, -11.93216568, -11.9466947,
    -11.86433498, -11.94421019, -11.92623012, -11.94499532,
    -11.93692585, -11.927615),
  cluster = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)),
  row.names = 1483:1495, class = "data.frame"
)

d = dist(df)
h = hclust(d)
cluster = cutree(h, k = 3)
df['cluster'] = cluster
```

I would like to continue partitioning the dataframe until I get groups with at most two elements and that preserves the hierarchy, a field like cluster father is enough. I know it's possible to do this directly, but I'd like to do it recursively, because I need to do a first grouping and then group the result. I racked my brains a lot to assemble a recursive algorithm, but so far I haven't been able to.

I researched how to work with trees in R, but I was not successful. Any solution would be valid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps a divisive cluster analysis such as `diana` ( divisive hierarchical clustering ) or `mona` (divisive hierarchical clustering of binary variables) in the `cluster` package?

Comment: @dcarlson, I don't know, from what I've seen from the R help, diana returns me a number of groups, which I would like to define how many elements at most each group can contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will apply `cutree(hclust(dist(df)))` to your data, then recursively apply it to each cluster within the last iteration. The main problem is how you represent this. Rather than creating new columns, I have chosen to append the subclusters as a character string, but this could be changed droending on your needs.

```r
repartition <- function(dat, k = 3) {

  multi_cut <- function(data, n = k) {
  
    cluster <- cutree(hclust(dist(data[1:2])), k = n)
    if(!"cluster" %in% names(data)) data$cluster <- cluster
    else data$cluster <- paste(data$cluster, cluster)
    do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, cluster), function(x) {
      if(nrow(x) < 3) return(x) else return(multi_cut(x, n = k))
    }))
  }
  
  dat <- multi_cut(dat)
  rownames(dat) <- NULL
  dat$cluster <- stringr::str_pad(dat$cluster, side = "right", 
                                  width = max(nchar(dat$cluster)))
  dat
}
```

testing it on your data we have:

```r
repartition(df)
#>    latitude longitude cluster
#> 1  23.13659 -11.64711 1      
#> 2  23.49100 -11.67840 2 1 1  
#> 3  23.49138 -11.68223 2 1 2  
#> 4  23.49053 -11.68326 2 1 3  
#> 5  23.45387 -11.94486 2 2 1 1
#> 6  23.45525 -11.94421 2 2 1 2
#> 7  23.45230 -11.94500 2 2 1 3
#> 8  23.44633 -11.94669 2 2 2  
#> 9  23.44412 -11.93693 2 2 3  
#> 10 23.44085 -11.93217 2 3 1  
#> 11 23.43415 -11.92623 2 3 2  
#> 12 23.43927 -11.92761 2 3 3  
#> 13 23.78720 -11.86433 3
```

---

**EDIT**

To access different levels of clustering, we could use `substr`. For example, plotting only the first level with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(repartition(df), 
       aes(longitude, latitude, color = substr(cluster, 1, 1))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Now plotting the second level:

```
ggplot(repartition(df), 
       aes(longitude, latitude, color = substr(cluster, 1, 3))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Interesting @Allan, although I liked your answer, what I need is to follow the index criterion (idx). This dataframe is the result of a grouping (the hclust function of R), I'm thinking of reapplying it until it only covers groups of two elements and some way to load the history of that cluster, by that parent cluster column. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @David can you show me the code that produced the data feame? This doesn't look like an hclust output

Comment: Hi @Allan, I've changed the codes in the question to what I'm actually working on. These are latitude and longitude data. I'm grouped places.

Comment: @David thanks. See my update. Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: Oh man, how beautiful! But how would I do a recursive search to find the distance to the center of each cluster? In the sense that I have a grouping, then within the grouping I have other groupings? How crazy.

Comment: @David you could simply use `substr` to take the first n characters of `cluster`. See my update seeing how that would work using ggplot